# Proper way to handle Model constants in Magento

Tags: php, magento, model-view-controller, constants

What is the proper way to handle constants in models with Magento?
For example, I have an `Export` class that have numerous status', such as

- Cancelled
- Pending
- Failed
- Complete

Currently, I have these defined at the top of the model like this, but I feel this is not the best solution:

```
  define("CANCELLED","Cancelled");
  define("INCOMPLETE","Incomplete");      
  define("PENDING","Pending");
  define("COMPLETE", "Complete");
```

For instance, in a controller, if I want to update the status of a sales order (which has custom fields that my model references) with PENDING, at the moment, I am running the below purely so that it includes the file that has the constants defined:

```
Mage::getModel("efinterface/export");
```

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you take a look at existing Magento code (Varien knowns how to code...) For example, the one class you're referring to ? : Mage_Sales_Model_Order and see all the `const STATE_NEW             = 'new';`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe define them as class constants

```
class SomeClass {
    const CANCELLED = 'Canceled';
    [...]
}
```

Then in your code `echo SomeClass::CANCELLED;` would give you the text `Canceled`

Comment: Thanks I was thinking about that- but then don't I need to include this class at various points in my code?

Comment: Your class will be autoloaded by name.

Comment: Where should I place this class? As a Model in the Model folder? When you say autoloaded by name, so Magento will autoload this class without explicitly specifying it anywhere?

Comment: if magento uses an autoloader, then yes, it will be loaded first time when called. And yes, model folder should do it.

Comment: Thanks. I've added the class to the Model folder, but when I call it, it can't find the class: `include(ExportStatus.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 93`

Comment: OK got it working by naming the class {company}_{module}_Model_ExportStatus. Thanks